# Why I have this error message while i'm trying to verify my snort configuration

Tags: networking, configure, snort

I'm trying to verify my snort configuration with 'snort -c C:\snort\etc\snort.conf –T' .The i got a failed message: 'ERROR: active response: can't open ip' like this one
[image]

I can't understand why i got this. Is there anyone can help me to fix this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You forget specify the interface -i 3 in my case, try it

snort -i 3 c: C:/snort/etc/snort.conf -T

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

By default, Snort attempts to open up a socket and fails because it does not have admin privileges.  Here is a [link](http://seclists.org/snort/2011/q2/730) I found about someone who had the same problem.

Run the command with elevated permissions (the Windows equivalent to sudo) to pass.